# apache wicket7 using https protocol

Tags: tomcat, openshift, wicket

We're trying to migrate our existing wicket application to use https and have followed the guide:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/single.html#security_3
Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected, if we call the HTTPS URL, we got the the error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in the browser
We're using wicket version 7.3.0. Any helps will be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add ***insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy = Redirect*** inside TLSConfig in openshift(v3.1)'s route configuration.